# I can't scroll down when the div show up

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, scrollbar

When I click on column on table it show a div with some informations , the div is a little bit long with plus than 400px in height, that why I need to scroll down to see it all , but unfortunately i can't ,even it exceed the hight of th webpage still nothing happened it like it not even there , the horizontal and vertical scroll bar work fine with table but not with the div  .
Here is the html of the div . :

```
 <div className='overlay'>
        <div className="container-vertical">
        <div className="point-vertical">
          <label className='noisy'>Noisy-le -Sec</label>
          <button className='button_veri_green'><img className='img_veri_green' src={veri_green}></img></button>
           <label className='gps'>93130, France | Type | Statut</label> </div>
        <div className="line-vertical"></div>
        <div className="point-vertical"><label className='noisy'>Noisy-le -Sec</label> <button className='button_veri_red'><img className='img_veri_green' src={veri_red}></img></button><label className='gps'>93130, France | Type | Statut</label> </div>
        <div className="line-vertical"></div>
        <div className="point-vertical"><label className='noisy'>Noisy-le -Sec</label> <label className='gps'>93130, France | Type | Statut</label> </div>
        <div className="line-vertical"></div>
        
        <div className="point-vertical"><button className='timer_btn'><img className='timer' src={timer}></img></button><label className='noisy'>Noisy-le -Sec</label><button className='x'><img className='img_veri_green' src={x}></img></button> <label className='gps'>93130, France | Type | Statut</label> </div>
        <div className="line-vertical"></div>
        <div className="point-vertical"><button className='question_mark_btn'><img className='question_mark' src={question_mark}></img></button> <label className='noisy'>Noisy-le -Sec</label> <label className='gps'>93130, France | Type | Statut</label> </div>
    
        <div className="dot-vertical"><img className='img-vertical' src={car_img} /></div>
    </div>
        </div>
```

the CSS :

```
.overlay {
  position: fixed;
  width: 458px;
  height: 422px;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  overflow-y: auto;
  box-shadow: 0px 3px 6px #1F1F1F29;
  z-index: 999; /* Set a high z-index value */
}
```

The js code that show it :

```
const overlay = document.querySelector('.overlay');

const tdWithProgression = document.querySelectorAll('.progression');

tdWithProgression.forEach(td => {

  td.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
    event.stopPropagation(); 
    const tr = td.parentElement; 
    const rowIndex = tr.rowIndex;
    const trows = document.querySelectorAll('tr');
    trows[rowIndex].style.background = 'white';
    
    // Calculate the position relative to the viewport
    const viewportTop = window.scrollY || window.pageYOffset;
    const viewportLeft = window.scrollX || window.pageXOffset;
    const topset = viewportTop + 200; // Adjust the top position as needed
    const leftset = viewportLeft;

    overlay.style.display = 'block';
    overlay.style.top = topset + 'px'; 
    overlay.style.left = leftset + 'px';
  });
});
```

I tried to add owerflow-y:auto or owerflow:auto , didn't work , I also tried to make vertical scroll always showed in the page but also didn't work with the div .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason the problem was in

```
 position:fixed
```

when I remove it , the position of the div get down but I was able to scroll down to see it , I had just to update the top in the function and it work well,
Here is CSS :

```
.overlay {
  position: relative;
  display: none; /* Initially hidden */
   /* Position it relative to the viewport */
  width: 458px;
  height: 422px;

  background: #FFFFFF 0% 0% no-repeat padding-box;
  z-index: 1000; /* Ensure it's on top of everything */
  /* Add other styles as needed */
  box-shadow: 0px 3px 6px #1F1F1F29;
}
```

and for Javascript I just change this line by adding "-200"

```
overlay.style.top = topset -200+ 'px';
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you're facing an issue where the content inside the `.overlay` div is not scrolling when its height exceeds the available space. To make sure the content inside the overlay can scroll properly, you should set a fixed height for the `.overlay` container and then apply `overflow-y: auto` to enable vertical scrolling when necessary. Here's how you can adjust your CSS:

```css
.overlay {
  position: fixed;
  width: 458px;
  max-height: 422px; /* Set a maximum height for scrolling */
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  overflow-y: auto; /* Enable vertical scrolling when content exceeds max-height */
  box-shadow: 0px 3px 6px #1F1F1F29;
  z-index: 999; /* Set a high z-index value */
}
```

In this CSS snippet, `max-height` is set to `422px`, which is the maximum height you want for your `.overlay` container. When the content inside exceeds this height, a vertical scrollbar will appear within the `.overlay` container, allowing users to scroll down to view the additional content.

Make sure to adjust the `max-height` value as needed to accommodate your content without causing the overlay to extend too far beyond the viewport.

Comment: I tried this but the div doesn't show up at all

Comment: I see you tried everything. To resolve the issue and enable scrolling in the `.overlay` div:

1. Check for CSS conflicts.
2. Use browser developer tools.
3. Ensure sufficient content.
4. Verify JavaScript event.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const overlay = document.querySelector('.overlay');
const tdWithProgression = document.querySelectorAll('.progression');

tdWithProgression.forEach((td) => {
  td.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
    event.stopPropagation();
    const tr = td.parentElement;
    const rowIndex = tr.rowIndex;
    const trows = document.querySelectorAll('tr');
    trows[rowIndex].style.background = 'white';

    // Show the overlay
    overlay.style.display = 'block';
  });
});

// Close the overlay when clicking inside it or outside it
document.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
  if (overlay.style.display === 'block') {
    overlay.style.display = 'none';
  }
});

// Prevent clicks inside the overlay from closing it
overlay.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
  event.stopPropagation();
});

// Close the overlay when clicking the "Close Overlay" button
const closeButton = document.querySelector('.close-overlay');
closeButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
  overlay.style.display = 'none';
});
```

```css
/* Add your existing CSS styles */
.overlay {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  width: 458px;
  height: 422px;
  top: 50%; /* Center vertically */
  left: 50%; /* Center horizontally */
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background: #FFFFFF;
  overflow-y: auto;
  box-shadow: 0px 3px 6px #1F1F1F29;
  z-index: 999;
}

.overlay-content {
  /* Add styling for the content within the overlay */
  padding: 20px; /* Adjust as needed */
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="progression">Column 1</td>
    <td class="progression">Column 2</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<div class="overlay">
  <div class="overlay-content">
    <h2>Overlay Content</h2>
    <p>This is some sample content inside the overlay.</p>
    <ul>
      <li>Item 1</li>
      <li>Item 2</li>
      <li>Item 3</li>
    </ul>
    <button class="close-overlay">Close Overlay</button>
  </div>
</div>
```